# Rubymine, "Debugger is not ready", hangs

Tags: rubymine

Quite often, when debugging in Rubymine, the variable inspector says "Debugger is not ready". What exactly does this mean and how can I avoid this?

Right now, this happens in this setup --

- one breakpoint in the controller
- another in the erb
- Hitting the controller breakpoint first, things work
- Hitting the erb one, the error occurs
- Clicking into the controller frame, the debugger still doesn't work

Continuing in the debugger, the breakpoint is left, but the web interface never returns anything. The browser keeps spinning.

Is there a deterministic way to make the debugger work?

Comment: It'd be great to have some reproduction steps and a project sample for that. Do you manage to reproduce it on the https://github.com/JetBrains/sample_rails_app? In addition, which RubyMine and Ruby SDK versions are you using?

Comment: I've tried the steps mentioned with the sample app, but debugger stopped in erb without any issue. That was in RubyMine 2023.1.2, Ruby 3.1.3

Comment: Same, debugger hangs - have to restart it every page load.